# Will navController.navigate() cause Android recomposition when I use Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the *end* branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab).

When I click the Tab of the UI, the App will show the corresponding UI, and the current Tab will be marked as a different style.

In *Overview.name* Tab UI page, if I click a account item, the code `composable(Overview.name) {...  onAccountClick = { name -> navigateToSingleAccount(navController, name) }` will navigate it to  `composable( route = "$accountsName/{name}", ..)` UI , and *Accounts.name*  is marked as current Tab.

What make me confuse is why Android can make *Accounts.name* as current Tab, could you tell me?  Will `navController.navigate()` cause Android `recomposition`? so is `val currentScreen = RallyScreen.fromRoute(backstackEntry.value?.destination?.route)` re-executed ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RallyApp() {
    RallyTheme {
        val allScreens = RallyScreen.values().toList()
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val backstackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentScreen = RallyScreen.fromRoute(backstackEntry.value?.destination?.route)

        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                RallyTabRow(
                    allScreens = allScreens,
                    onTabSelected = { screen ->
                        navController.navigate(screen.name)
                    },
                    currentScreen = currentScreen
                )
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            RallyNavHost(navController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RallyNavHost(navController: NavHostController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Overview.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(Overview.name) {
           OverviewBody(
                onClickSeeAllAccounts = { navController.navigate(Accounts.name) },
                onClickSeeAllBills = { navController.navigate(Bills.name) },
                onAccountClick = { name ->
                    navigateToSingleAccount(navController, name)
                },
            )
        }

        composable(Accounts.name) {
            AccountsBody(accounts = UserData.accounts) { name ->
                navigateToSingleAccount(navController = navController, accountName = name)
            }
        }
        composable(Bills.name) {
           ...
        }


        val accountsName = Accounts.name
        composable(
            route = "$accountsName/{name}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("name") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            ),
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink {
                    uriPattern = "rally://$accountsName/{name}"
                }
            ),
        ) { entry ->
            val accountName = entry.arguments?.getString("name")
            val account = UserData.getAccount(accountName)
            SingleAccountBody(account = account)
        }
    }
}

private fun navigateToSingleAccount(navController: NavHostController, accountName: String) {
    navController.navigate("${Accounts.name}/$accountName")
}


enum class RallyScreen(
    val icon: ImageVector,
) {
    Overview(
        icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
    ),
    Accounts(
        icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
    ),
    Bills(
        icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,
    );

    companion object {
        fun fromRoute(route: String?): RallyScreen =
            when (route?.substringBefore("/")) {
                Accounts.name -> Accounts
                Bills.name -> Bills
                Overview.name -> Overview
                null -> Overview
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Route $route is not recognized.")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `navigate()` will definitely cause recomposition as the UI is getting re-created.

Yes, `val currentScreen = RallyScreen.fromRoute(backstackEntry.value?.destination?.route)` will be re-executed as `backstackEntry` is being observed as state and its value will change when you navigate. That's why the `RallyApp` composable will also get recomposed. So when it is executed again, `currentScreen` value will get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Effects as per your requirement. In this scenario, you can use `LaunchedEffect`. like,

```
LaunchedEffect(null) {
    // code that you don't want to run again.
}
```

Another approach for now(Which I do not recommend), to avoid your composable code from re-running by checking the current route in the back-stack entry and your expected route. To do that you can use the following piece of code.

```
@Composable
fun YourComposableScreen(navController: NavController) {
    if (yourExpectedRoute != navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
        return
    }
    // Your other composable(s) goes here. 
}
```